# DataGrid only update rows that are shown

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that contains a few Name - Value Pairs, the said Name - Value Pairs are polled from a hardware device. To increase Performance (of the Polling loop not of the UI) I want to know which Items of the Binding are shown.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ParameterViewSource.View}" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"/>
```

The DataGrid does now Virtualize the Rows by default. But for my background polling loop I want to know which Items of my CollectionViewSource currently are inside a RowPresenter.

The approach should be realizable in MVVM.

I tried to use the DataGridRowsPresenter - and the Children (or more specific there DataContext), but I am unable to get notified about changes. Is there any easy way to a achieve what I want.

```
private static void GridOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
            var rowPresenter = grid.FindChildRecursive<DataGridRowsPresenter>();

            var items = rowPresenter.Children.OfType<DataGridRow>()
            .Select(x => x.DataContext);
            //Works but does not get notified about changes to the Children 
            //collection which occure if i resize the Grid, Collapse a 
            //Detail Row and so on
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using a attached Property:

```
public class DataGridHelper
{
     //I skipped the attached Properties (IsAttached, StartIndex and Count) declarations        


    private static void IsAttachedPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)dependencyObject;
        grid.Loaded += GridOnLoaded;
    }

    private static void GridOnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
        ScrollBar scrollBar = grid.FindChildRecursive<ScrollBar>("PART_VerticalScrollBar");

        if (scrollBar != null)
        {
            scrollBar.ValueChanged += (o, args) => SetVisibleItems(grid, scrollBar);

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(RangeBase.MaximumProperty, typeof (ScrollBar));
            descriptor.AddValueChanged(scrollBar, (o, args) => SetVisibleItems(grid, scrollBar));

            SetVisibleItems(grid, scrollBar);
        }
    }

    private static void SetVisibleItems(DataGrid grid, ScrollBar scrollBar)
    {
        int startIndex = (int)Math.Floor(scrollBar.Value);
        int count = (int)Math.Ceiling(grid.Items.Count - scrollBar.Maximum);

        SetStartIndex(grid, startIndex);
        SetCount(grid, count);
    }
```

and then bound the attached Properties of my DataGrid to some view Model Properties using OneWayToSource.

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ParameterViewSource.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  userInterface:DataGridHelper.IsAttached="True"
                  userInterface:DataGridHelper.Count="{Binding Path=Count, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                  userInterface:DataGridHelper.StartIndex="{Binding Path=StartIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

You can also handle the Count and StartIndex on the DataGrid and extract the SubArray of the Items Property.